# watchdog watchdog0 watchdog did not stop

Tags: bios, reboot, watchdog, acpi

I have a computer that always has issues restarting/shutting down. I've installed many Linux distributions on it, including Debian 9 and VMware Photon OS, and I always have the same issue.

When I restart, the machines does not actually restart, it rather stops at a message saying "watchdog watchdog0: watchdog did not stop!" and simply sits there, doing nothing.

I have tried changing **GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""** to **GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="reboot=bios"** and **GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="reboot=acpi"**

I have also configured **RuntimeWatchdogSec** and **ShutdownWatchdogSec** to **0**

I have also **enabled** and **disabled** acpi in the bios

I also tried **systemctl reboot**, **shutdown -r now**, **init 6** and various other suggestions I found online.

But no luck. The behavior does not change, the computer does not restart, it just stays there showing **watchdog watchdog0: watchdog did not stop!**

I don't have the same issue on other computers, so my guess is that there's something wrong with the bios settings on this computer, I just can't figure out what. I've reset the bios to it's default settings, but again, no luck.

Any suggestions?